# Python decorator variable score

Tags: python, closures, scope, decorator

I created a simple decorator that received an argument (using functions instead of a class), when something strage happened: adding a line a code breaks the execution of a previous line.

Here's the code:

```
def my_decorator(sublabel):
    def duration_wrapper(f):

        print sublabel
        # Uncommenting this code will break the previous line - why?
        # if sublabel is None:
        #     sublabel = f.func_name

        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped_function

    return duration_wrapper

@my_decorator('me')
def myf(): pass

myf()
```

Uncommenting those lines of code cause this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    @my_decorator('me')
  File "test.py", line 4, in duration_wrapper
    print sublabel
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sublabel' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone explain why uncommenting those 2 lines of code break it?

Comment: What is the exact error or traceback, please post it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decorators are closures, and all labels from an enclosing scope referenced from an enclosed scope must remain static within the enclosed scope.  If you want to have a variable from an enclosing scope be mutable from an enclosed scope, you need to wrap it in a mutable object, for example:

```
def my_decorator(sublabel):
    sublabel = [sublabel]
    def duration_wrapper(f):

        print sublabel[0]
        if sublabel[0] is None:
            sublabel[0] = f.func_name

        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped_function

    return duration_wrapper
```

As @Bakuriu notes in the comments, Python 3 introduces `nonlocal` to remove this restriction, and you could also make `sublabel` a global to get around the problem, but globals are usually a bad idea generally.

Comment: You ought to mention the fact that in python3 you can use `nonlocal` to modify variables from outerscopes and also you could cite `global` to modify global variables.

Comment: @Bakuriu He's using the version < 3 syntax for `print`, so for this case, this is correct, but I'll add the note.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be reduced to this simple example

```
sublevel = 1

def func():
    print sublevel
    sublevel = 2

func()
```

Problem is when you assign a variable in innner scope you are masking the outer scope (global level or parent function level scope), read docs to see how [python scope rules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) work, important thing to notice is that `scopes are determined statically`

So in my example you need to say `global sublevel` before calling print and your case you need to use `nonlocal` keyword (python 3+)

Comment: Your code will work just fine.  The restriction only comes in to play when the function is a closure.

Comment: @sr2222 it is almost same problem due to masking of parent variable, in my case you will get error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sublevel' referenced before assignment"